# VSTS REST api add project admin in C#

Tags: c#, azure-devops, bots, project, azure-devops-rest-api

I am currently working on a chatbot that creates VSTS projects on demand.
So far it works but it needs to add the user that requested the creation to the project as an administator.
I can get the UserID and ProjectID without an issue but the documentation isnt really helpfull when it comes to adding users as admins to a project.

This is the closest I have gotten to a working request:

Request in Fiddler
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hmIK.png)

I know that the values are propably wrong but I cant seem to figure out whats wrong and the error message only says that the document is invalid:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: Do not post images of classes, requests and any sort of item that you can copy as a text. This helps us ( the answerers ) to actually help you. By posting it as a text someone can easily copy, paste and analyze that particular text within his/hers tools.

Answer (score 0):

To make a user a Project Admin, you have to add the user to the Project Administrators group. This can be done via the AddIdentities API:

```
POST https://{{vsts}}.visualstudio.com/{{projectid}}/_api/_identity/AddIdentities?__v=5
Authorization: {{auth}}
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "newUsersJson":"[]",
  "existingUsersJson":"[\"{{userIdToAdd}}\"]",
  "groupsToJoinJson":"[\"{{tfIdOfProjectAdministratorsGroup}}\"]",
  "aadGroupsJson":"[]"
}
```

Replace {{var}} with the actual values.

To find out the tfIdOfProjectAdministratorsGroup, you can use the following API:

```
GET https://{{vsts}}.visualstudio.com/{{projectId}}/_api/_identity/ReadScopedApplicationGroupsJson?__v=5
```

The response has an object with "FriendlyDisplayName": "Project Administrators". You need the TeamFoundationId of this object.

Comment: Alright I did it like that, but now it says that the header is invalid. The project Id should be correct, I got it from another GET request. And with "tfIdOfProjectAdministratorsGroup" do you mean the originID of the group?

Comment: It is the ID of the Project Administrators group.

Comment: Maybe I should have said that, but I am very new to this. All I can see is the "originID" when I do this request: GET https://name.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/graph/groups?api-version=4.1-preview.1                  ----     and that doesnt fix that the header in on itselfe has an issue. I did it as you wrote: https://name.visualstudio.com/fa891d93-06fb-40c9-bd49-f0d09807f127/_api/_identity/AddIdentities?_v=5

Comment: Are we maybe speaking of different things? Every api I used from you always gave the error: Bad Request - Invalid Header ---  HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name.                Not that the project doesnt exists or something, but that the request header is just wrong....

Comment: Did you add the authorization to the header? Your encoded PAT should be in there.    From curl:  curl --request POST   --url 'https://{{vsts}}.visualstudio.com/{{IdOfProject}}/_api/_identity/AddIdentities?__v=5'   --header 'authorization: Basic {{base64Of(:PAT)}}'   --header 'content-type: application/json'   --data '{"newUsersJson":"[]","existingUsersJson":"[\"4e19e5bd-fca1-4ee0-b682-8c0249f8e51e\"]","groupsToJoinJson":"[\"92c5ff70-299d-4128-aaea-e67de954d90c\"]"}'

Comment: I used the same authorization that I used for all my other requests that work.